# Why isnt a random port chosen for SEED node sockets?

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-core, client, tcp

I connected a node `A` to bitcoin `testnet` (Port 18333). The node discovery happens and I see couple of connections between my node `A` and the seed nodes. All of the sending and receiving happens between nodes ONLY via Port 18333 (I checked this in `ThreadSocketHandler`)

I add another node `B` (different laptop hence different IP) to the bitcoin `testnet`. I initiate a `addnode <lappyB_IP>:18333 onetry` connection from `A` and it gets accepted. But now the port `A` uses to send data is chosen randomly by OS and NOT 18333. This can be checked by
`getpeerinfo`

We should note that both are **outbound** connections from `A` -- namely the first one is we connected to seednode and send one is we connected to another node `B`. How come in the former data is getting sent via 18333 (default port) but in the later OS decides to chose a different port?

Comment: Can you show the getpeerinfo?  The addrlocal port should be random for all outbound connections and 18333 for all inbound connections

Comment: The addrlocal is empty. So the `rpcnet.cpp` logic suppresses it in `getpeerinfo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All nodes are listening on port 18333 for inbound connections.  Any inbound connection will use this port.  So addrlocal will show localIP:18333.

Any outbound connection will use a random port so addrlocal will show localIP:xxxxx

So every connection is either random <----> 18333  OR 18333 <----> random.  The node that initiated the connection (out) will always use a random port.

This is how all tcp/ip web services with known ports work.  Web servers listen on port 80 or port 443, browsers use a random local port to connect to them.

Edit: Should note that port 18333 is for testnet nodes. Would be 8333 for main net.  Also if on linux `netstat -ntlp` or `netstat -ntp` will show all tcp connections

Comment: Is there a possibility to make it 18333 <---> 18333 ? Like passing an option to system call and telling OS to use specified instead of random source port?

Comment: @GuhanS You can do this on Linux with `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range="18333 18333"` (Note: This will make it so you can only have one outbound connection at once.)

Comment: @GuhanS If you're talking about modifying Bitcoin to choose that port automatically, [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711608/linux-how-to-send-tcp-packet-from-specific-port) will probably be helpful.

Comment: Yes exactly what I wanted. You guys are amazing!